# How to assign resources to a Task in a bug tracker application under development

Tags: architecture

What are your ideas and suggestions on how to assign Issues in bug tracker application to individual developers when a new Issue is created?

If the settings should be stored in a database, what would the table look like?
What will trigger the resource assignment?
For example, when the user clicks the submit button, we look into the assignment settings table to figure out who the developer is for the ProjectId and IssueTypeId, and insert the UserId of the developer into the IssueResource table.
What if there are more than developers assigned to a IssueType in a Project, how do we handle this scenario?

**My Tables**

Issue
IssueId UserId ProjectId Description

IssueType
IssueTypeId Description

IssueResource
IssueResourceId UserId IssueId

Answer (score 0):

I would first ask why this is home grown but I doubt it's worth while.  Assign a primary and let them delegate I suppose.

Comment: "I would first ask why this is home grown but I doubt it's worth while". Gren, can you please elaborate. I would like to hear your thoughts and suggestions.

Comment: The are plenty of bug trackers available http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue_tracking_systems and I would think that one of them should meet your needs.  In my experience, developing your own software to manage your software development is not the best use of your resources.  Unless of course your going to make that your product.

Comment: +1 Gren, good point. My tracker is for an intranet and for security reasons we would like to keep it in house.

Comment: Most trackers do not need to be hosted externally.  Bugzilla and Mantis are the free ones that come to mind.  I'd say you're currently paying for it now so maybe you could look into a commercial product that you can host like fogbugz http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/